# Unable to remap CapsLock key on AwesomeWM with iBus-Mozc

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, awesome

I'm trying to remap <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, but seems unable to remap in all ways.

Also, the key has a strange behavior.

First, I use japanese keyboard. Therefore, `XKBLAYOUT = "jp"` in `/etc/default/keyboard`.

And I use Awesome as an Window Manager. While I login using gnome, <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> works as <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>. However, When I login using AwesomeWM, <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> do nothing.

I want to use <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on Awesome. I have tried followings:

- `setxkbmap` -- `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps`.
- `.xmodmap`
- add a `.conf` file to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`
- edit `XKBOPTION` in `/etc/default/keyboard`

However, all of these are never able <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to work as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, although `xev` and `xmodmap -pke` returns that CapsLock(keycode 66) is mapped to Ctrl-L.

Also, only when I map <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> like that I write `keycode 66 = Caps_Lock` in `.xmodmap`, the key works. If I tried to map to other keys than CapsLock like <kbd>Esc</kbd>, the key don't do its work as it didn't in the case of Ctrl.

Does anyone knows what happens?

Answer (score 1):

I use `setxkbmap` and `xcape` to remap <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>.
Holding down <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and short press results in <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Those tools may help.

I have the following in my `.xinitrc`:

```
setxkbmap -option 'caps:ctrl_modifier'
xcape -e 'Caps_Lock=Escape'
```